# como obtener el id de un formulario en jquery y js

Tags: javascript, jquery

este es mi codigo quisiera saber como obtener el id:(

[image: Este es mi código en estos momentos, como pueden ver solo me falta el id y estoy algo perdida con eso]

Comment: Bienvenida a SO, te recomiendo agregar el código de tu script, de esta forma es más fácil ejemplificar, podrías leer [ask] y [mcve] para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas por la comunidad.

Comment: Yo no logro visualizar tu código recuerda agregarlo como texto y no como imagen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con `$(row).attr("id").`
No he podio probar tu código, pero tal vez te ayude.

Saludos!!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes acceder al atributo `id`de un elemento con `.attr('id')`, por ejempllo en tu caso:

```
filas.each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('id') !== 'row0') {
        permissions.push({
            id: $(this).attr('id'),
            description: $(this).closest('td').text()
        });
    }
});
```